# How add data in django serializer only once

Tags: django

I have a django serializer as below,

```
class VideoSerializer(CustomSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = apis_models.Video
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, video):
        data = super().to_representation(video)

        return {

                'ordering': {
                        'video': {
                            "label": "Order By",
                            "options": {
                                "Newest First": '-upload_date',
                                "Oldest First": 'upload_date',
                                "Views (High)": "views",
                                "Views (Low)": "-views"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                'body': data,
        }
```

Which prints the output as below.

The "ordering" key appears in each element.

I need it to be appear only once at top. I believe using to_representation would be the best way to do it since it is a constant value. But I am not sure how do I get it only once.

How could I get it? Please help.

```
{
    "count": 339,
    "next": "http://10.0.0.238:8000/videos/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "ordering": {
                "video": {
                    "label": "Order By",
                    "options": {
                        "Newest First": "-upload_date",
                        "Oldest First": "upload_date",
                        "Views (High)": "views",
                        "Views (Low)": "-views"
                    }
                }
            },
            "body": {
                "id": 6142,
                "source": {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "kpopdeepfakes_net",
                    "domain": "https://kpopdeepfakes.net",
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "ordering": {
                "video": {
                    "label": "Order By",
                    "options": {
                        "Newest First": "-upload_date",
                        "Oldest First": "upload_date",
                        "Views (High)": "views",
                        "Views (Low)": "-views"
                    }
                }
            },
            "body": {
                "id": 6153,
                "source": {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "kpopdeepfakes_net",
                    "domain": "https://kpopdeepfakes.net",
                 }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by adding below to my viewset.

```
def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    return Response({
        'ordering': {
                    'video': {
                        "label": "Order By",
                        "options": {
                            "Newest First": '-upload_date',
                            "Oldest First": 'upload_date',
                            "Views (High)": "views",
                            "Views (Low)": "-views"
                        }
                    }
                },
        'results': data
    })
```